# Selecting multiple attributes using BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, css, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract content from html that looks like this

```
<div type="alpha" content="upper-left" experience="summary_resource">
```

I want to select all instances that match exactly the type, content, and experience

```
soup.select('div[type="alpha"][content="upper-left"][experience="summary_resource"]')
```

I get an unsupported or invalid CSS selector error if I try to use the above code. Searching for the attributes individually works, but I want to chain them using select like I would if I wanted to chain select classes.

Comment: It turns out that my version of beautifulsoup4 was outdated and did not support the type of css selectors that I showed. Make sure to have the most up to date bs4 version for proper selector chaining.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get a list of those elements, you could try:

```
allInstances = soup.findAll('div', {'experience':'summary_resource'})
```

then you can get each element's content like this:

```
print(allInstances[0].text)
```

It is possible to add more attributes to the dictionary